# ODB: unresolved external symbol error when including *.hxx file with common declarations

Tags: c++, linker-errors, unresolved-external, odb

I must use the [ODB framework](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/) in my project. I have 2 files: `station.hxx` and `common.hxx` with following content:

**common.hxx**

```
#ifndef COMMON_HXX
#define COMMON_HXX

#include <string>

#pragma db value
struct ProcessAggregateName
{
#pragma db column("SHORTNAME")
   std::string SHORTNAME;
#pragma db column("LONGNAME")
   std::string LONGNAME;
#pragma db column("SECONDARYNAME")
   std::string SECONDARYNAME;
};

#pragma db value
struct Reporting
{
#pragma db column("OPERATIONALLOG")
   std::string OPERATIONALLOG;
#pragma db column("PRINTER")
   std::string PRINTER;
#pragma db column("HIGHLIGHTING")
   bool HIGHLIGHTING;
#pragma db column("REPORTTYPE")
   std::string REPORTTYPE;
};

#endif // COMMON_HXX
```

**station.hxx**

```
#ifndef STATION_HXX
#define STATION_HXX

#include <string>

#include "common.hxx"

#pragma db object table("STATION")
class station
{
public:
   station () {}

   #pragma db id column("ID")
   int ID;
   #pragma db column("OPERATINGDOMAIN")
   long OPERATINGDOMAIN;
   #pragma db column("NAME")
   ProcessAggregateName NAME;
   #pragma db column("EXPORTBASICDATA")
   bool EXPORTBASICDATA;
   #pragma db column("EXPORTPROCESSDATA")
   bool EXPORTPROCESSDATA;
   #pragma db column("IMPORTBASICDATA")
   bool IMPORTBASICDATA;
   #pragma db column("IMPORTPROCESSDATA")
   bool IMPORTPROCESSDATA;
   #pragma db column("REPORTING")
   Reporting REPORTING;
};

#endif // STATION_HXX
```

The reason for this: I want to use structures declared in `common.hxx` also in other files, so I wanted to concentrate them in the same header file and include it whereever I need them. My problem: if I do it this way, I get linker errors like these:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl
>   odb::access::composite_value_traits::bind(struct odb::mssql::bind *,struct
>   odb::access::composite_value_traits::image_type &,enum
>   odb::mssql::statement_kind)"
>   (?bind@?$composite_value_traits@UProcessAggregateName@@$03@access@odb@@SAXPAU0mssql@3@AAUimage_type@123@W4statement_kind@43@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl
>   odb::access::object_traits_impl::bind(struct
>   odb::mssql::bind *,struct odb::access::object_traits_impl::image_type &,enum odb::mssql::statement_kind)"
>   (?bind@?$object_traits_impl@Vstation@@$03@access@odb@@SAXPAU0mssql@3@AAUimage_type@123@W4statement_kind@43@@Z)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl
>   odb::access::composite_value_traits::init(struct
>   odb::access::composite_value_traits::image_type &,struct ProcessAggregateName
>   const &,enum odb::mssql::statement_kind)"
>   (?init@?$composite_value_traits@UProcessAggregateName@@$03@access@odb@@SAXAAUimage_type@123@ABUProcessAggregateName@@W4statement_kind@mssql@3@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl
>   odb::access::object_traits_impl::init(struct
>   odb::access::object_traits_impl::image_type &,class
>   station const &,enum odb::mssql::statement_kind)"
>   (?init@?$object_traits_impl@Vstation@@$03@access@odb@@SAXAAUimage_type@123@ABVstation@@W4statement_kind@mssql@3@@Z)

If I copy the declaration of `ProcessAggregateName` and `Reporting` into `station.hxx` directly instead of including `common.hxx`, everything goes fine. What do I do wrong and how can I declare commonly used structures in a single header and include it in multiple *.hxx files?

Comment: When you generated the files using `odb` it will have made one or more `.cxx` files. These need to be linked with the application or you will experience this error.

Comment: @Petesh, thanks for you reply. Indeed, this seems to solve the problem. I had `station.hxx` and `common.hxx` themselves as part of my project, but not the generated *.cxx and *.ixx files. If I add them to the project, I can build it completely. Please enter your reply as answer and I will upvote and mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `odb` compiler/code generator creates three elements for the persistence layer - `.hxx`, `.ixx` and `.cxx` files. The `.hxx` and `.ixx` files contain the declarations of the types that are needed to perform the persistence. These will satisfy the compiler when building - you tell it what the interface looks like.

However, in order to use the code, you need the implementation files (the definitions). These are only present in the `.cxx` files.

Without the `.cxx` files, you get the `odb::access`… linker errors; these indicate that the code behind the declarations are missing.

Once you make sure that the `.cxx` files are compiled and linked into your project, the compilation should succeed.